# looping over several dataframes using coxph and mstate in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply, lapply, survival

How do write a function or loop to iterate this procedure which uses the mstate() package over several dataframes (cohort1 - cohort25)?

sample data:

```
impute1 <- data.frame(unique_ID = c(1,2,3,4), 
                  DIED_INDICATOR = c(0,1,1,1), 
                  CVD_ANY = c(0,1,1,0), 
                  YEARS_CVD_DEATH = c(15.9, 23.6, 22.7, 3.4), 
                  YEARS_CVD_HOSP = c(15.9, 11.4, 22.7, 3.4), 
                  TOBACCO = c(0, 0, 0, 1), 
                  MARRIED = c(1,0,1,0), 
                  PARITY = c(2,1,1,2)) 

impute2 <- data.frame(unique_ID = c(1,2,3,4), 
                  DIED_INDICATOR = c(0,1,1,1), 
                  CVD_ANY = c(0,1,1,0), 
                  YEARS_CVD_DEATH = c(15.9, 23.6, 22.7, 3.4), 
                  YEARS_CVD_HOSP = c(15.9, 11.4, 22.7, 3.4), 
                  TOBACCO = c(0, 1, 0, 1), 
                  MARRIED = c(1,0,1,1), 
                  PARITY = c(1,1,1,2)) 


covs<-c("TOBACCO", "MARRIED", "PARITY")
```

Code to run model over 1 dataframe:

```
cohort1 <- msprep(data=impute1,trans=tmat, 
             time=c(NA,"YEARS_CVD_HOSP","YEARS_CVD_DEATH"),
             status=c(NA,"CVD_ANY","DIED_INDICATOR"), 
             keep=covs,
             id = as.vector(impute1$unique_ID))

cohort_expand<-expand.covs(cohort1, covs, append = TRUE, longnames = FALSE)

c1<-coxph(Surv(Tstart, Tstop, status)~TOBACCO.1 + TOBACCO.2 + 
TOBACCO.3 + strata(trans),     data=cohort1, method = "breslow")
summary(c1)

newdata<-data.frame(trans=1:3, TOBACCO.1 = c(0,0,0), TOBACCO.2 = 
c(0,0,0), TOBACCO.3 = c(0,0,0), strata = 1:3)

msf1<-msfit(c1, newdata, trans=tmat)

plot(msf1, las=1, lty=rep(1:2,c(8,4)), xlab="Years")
```

I loaded 25 dataframes into a list:

```
path <- ''
print(path)
files <- list.files(path = path, pattern="*.sas7bdat", full.names=FALSE)
print(files)

impute <- list()
for (i in 1:length(files)){
  filename <- paste0(path, files[i])
  print(filename)
  impute[[i]] <- haven::read_sas(data_file=filename)
  print(names(impute[[i]]))
  eval(parse(text = paste0("impute", i, " <- 
haven::read_sas(data_file=filename)")))
}
```

I'm trying to write a function for the msprep step using the first two imputed datasets.

```
test_list <- list(impute1, impute2)

my_func <- function(x) {
    cohort<-mstate::msprep(data=test_list,trans=tmat, 
               time=c(NA,"YEARS_CVD_HOSP","YEARS_CVD_DEATH"),
               status=c(NA,"CVD_ANY","DIED_INDICATOR"), 
               keep=covs,
               id = as.vector(test_list$unique_ID))
}


test<-lapply(test_list, my_func)
```

I get an error:

Error in mstate::msprep(data = test_list, trans = tmat, time = c(NA, "YEARS_CVD_HOSP",  :
argument "id" is not a vector

How can I specify unique_ID as a vector even though it is a list?

Next function:

```
test<-lapply(test_list, my_func2)

my_func2 <- function(x) {
             cohort<-mstate::cohort<-expand.covs(cohort, covs, append = 
             TRUE, longnames = FALSE)
}
```

I've also tried using the lapply function for iterating coxph model over the dataset but how do I write the code for then entire procedure ?

```
c1<- lapply(mydf , function(i) {
  
 iformula <- as.formula(sprintf("Surv(Tstart, Tstop, status) 
~TOBACCO.1 + TOBACCO.2 + TOBACCO.3 +   strata(trans)", i))  

})
```

Comment: Could you give us some example data?

Comment: impute1 <- data.frame(unique_ID       = c(1,2,3,4),
                      DIED_INDICATOR  = c(0,1,1,1),
                      CVD_ANY         = c(0,1,1,0),
                      YEARS_CVD_DEATH = c(15.9, 23.6, 22.7, 3.4),
                      YEARS_CVD_HOSP  = c(15.9, 11.4, 22.7, 3.4),
                      TOBACCO         = c(0, 0, 0, 1),
                      MARRIED         = c(1,0,1,0),
                      PARITY          = c(2,1,1,2))

    covs<-c("TOBACCO", "MARRIED", "PARITY")

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing about proportional hazards regression, but I too your code and put it into a function. It's fairly simple, with a single argument, `x`, which is passed on to the `data` and `id` arguments in `msprep()`. The rest is kept pretty much as is, except `data` in `coxph()` was changed to `cohort_expand`. `tmat` and `newdata` were moved outside the function, as they appear to be constant.

```
library(mstate)

impute1 <- data.frame(unique_ID = c(1,2,3,4), 
                  DIED_INDICATOR = c(0,1,1,1), 
                  CVD_ANY = c(0,1,1,0), 
                  YEARS_CVD_DEATH = c(15.9, 23.6, 22.7, 3.4), 
                  YEARS_CVD_HOSP = c(15.9, 11.4, 20.7, 3.4), 
                  TOBACCO = c(0, 0, 0, 1), 
                  MARRIED = c(1,0,1,0), 
                  PARITY = c(2,1,1,2)) 

impute2 <- data.frame(unique_ID = c(1,2,3,4), 
                  DIED_INDICATOR = c(0,1,1,1), 
                  CVD_ANY = c(0,1,1,0), 
                  YEARS_CVD_DEATH = c(15.9, 23.6, 22.7, 3.4), 
                  YEARS_CVD_HOSP = c(15.9, 11.4, 21.7, 3.4), 
                  TOBACCO = c(0, 1, 0, 1), 
                  MARRIED = c(1,0,1,1), 
                  PARITY = c(1,1,1,2)) 


test_list <- list(impute1, impute2)

covs <- c("TOBACCO", "MARRIED", "PARITY")

tmat <- trans.illdeath()

newdata <- data.frame(trans=1:3, TOBACCO.1=c(0,0,0), 
  TOBACCO.2=c(0,0,0), TOBACCO.3=c(0,0,0), strata=1:3)


my_func2 <- function(x) {
    cohort1 <- msprep(data=x, trans=tmat, 
      time=c(NA,"YEARS_CVD_HOSP","YEARS_CVD_DEATH"),
      status=c(NA,"CVD_ANY","DIED_INDICATOR"), 
      keep=covs, id=x$unique_ID)

    cohort_expand <- expand.covs(cohort1, covs, append=TRUE, longnames=FALSE)

    c1 <- coxph(Surv(Tstart, Tstop, status) 
      ~ TOBACCO.1 + TOBACCO.2 + TOBACCO.3 + strata(trans),
      data=cohort_expand, method="breslow")

    msfit(c1, newdata, trans=tmat)
}

fits <- lapply(test_list, my_func2)

par(mfrow=c(2, 1), mar=c(3, 3, 1, 1), mgp=c(1.5, 0.5, 0))
zzz <- lapply(fits, plot)
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted since I think it's "useful" but of questionable correctness as you admit. I know quite a bit about Cox proportional hazards modeling and one thing I do know is that a cumulative hazard  (which I think is being displayed rather than an actual "Hazard") of 1.0e+09 is effectively infinite. I in turn admit that I know nothing about the "mstate" package.